# Prove $\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln|x|+C$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can anyone show me how id prove this fact? I have no clue where to begin so any hints to help or full answers would be great!

Comment: How about taking the derivative of right hand side?

Comment: What's your definition of $\ln{x}$? A lot of people simply define it as the integral of $1/x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you suspect that $\int\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x=\log|x|+C$, you can simply take the derivative to verify:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(x)=\frac1x\quad\text{when }x\gt0
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(-x)=\frac1x\quad\text{when }x\lt0
$$
If you don't suspect $\log|x|+C$, you can use
$$
\int x^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{n+1}\left(x^{n+1}-1\right)+C
$$
as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498449).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps
$$
\int \frac{1}{x}\;dx = \ln|x|+C
$$
is misleading.  First, it is false for complex $x$.  Second, for real $x$, it is shorthand for
$$
\int\frac{1}{x}\;dx = \ln x + C \qquad\text{on intervals where $x>0$ and}
\\
\int\frac{1}{x}\;dx = \ln(-x) + D \qquad\text{on intervals where $x<0$.}
$$
The constants $C$ and $D$ need not be the same.