# $f(x)=\log x\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=e^x$. Why $e=2.73\cdots$?

Tags: special-functions, education

> $$f(x)=\log x\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=e^x.$$

Ok, $\log x$ is defined as the function $f(\cdot)$ such that: $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$. How to get, from this, the inverse of it $f^{-1}(x)$? And why $e=2.73\cdots$?

Comment: actually just saying that $f'(x) = 1/x$ doesnt necassirly mean that $f = \ln(x)$. for all constants $c$ you have $(\ln(x) + c)' = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Another recent [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837180/how-to-see-the-logarithm-as-the-inverse-function-of-the-exponential).

Comment: The approximation 2.73 for e is quite bad. At least use 2.72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer has not answered your question, “Why is $e$ equal to $2.718281828\cdots$?”.

Let’s form the number $E=\lim_n(1+\frac1n)^n$, and evaluate it knowing the continuity of the log function and what its derivative is. Of course this number $E$ is computable, even if slowly, directly by hand. And if you take $n$ large enough, you will indeed find that your result is close to the number I quoted above.

We have:
$$
\log(E)=\log\left[\lim_n(1+\frac1n)^n\right]=\lim_n\frac{\log(1+\frac1n)-\log(1)}{1/n}=\log'(1)=1/1\,,
$$
just using the definition of the derivative and applying it to the logarithm. So $\log(E)=1$, and I think that’s what you wanted to know.

Comment: +1. I cannot upvote though.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to impose $\log(1) = 0$; otherwise, it's only determined up to a constant. The inverse $f^{-1}$ has derivative
$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))} = f^{-1}(x)$$
and $f^{-1}(0) = 1$ ; this is exactly the definition (well, one definition) of $e^x$.