# Logarithm as limiting case of $n$th root

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, logarithms

Let $f_n(x) = x^{1/n}$ where $n \in \mathbb N$, and let $g(x) = \log(x)$. We can compute $f_n'(x) = \frac{1}{n}x^{-1 + \frac{1}{n}}$ and $g'(x) = x^{-1}$. Let's define $f_\infty(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$. It will be everywhere assumed that $x > 0$.

If I've computed it correctly, it seems that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n'(x) = 0$ for any fixed $x > 0$.  This means that for each $x \in \mathbb R^+$ $f_\infty$ is flat while $g$ is not.

But if instead we compute $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{g(x)}$ for a fixed $n \in \mathbb N$ then we find that this limit equals $\infty$, suggesting that for each finite $n$ $f_n$ grows faster.

Initially I was thinking that maybe $\log$ was like the limiting case of $f_n$ but now I'm not so sure. Part of the issue is reconciling these two limits.

My question, then, is: can we think of $\log$ as the limiting case of $f_n$? If not, why?

Comment: Observe that $\;\displaystyle\int x^{-1+1/n} \, dx=\frac{x^{1/n}}{1/n} + C=\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{1/n} +C'\;$ and that the limit as $n\to\infty$ will indeed be $\log(x)$ from this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498339/demystify-integration-of-int-frac1x-mathrm-dx).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni that is very helpful. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it clarified things @alfalfa! Fine continuation,

Comment: It is not difficult to develop a theory of logarithmic and exponential functions starting from the definition $\log x = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1)$. See http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the link. Now that you point that out, it seems really obvious that $(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = y \implies n(y^{1/n} - 1) = x$ so this clearly is the natural choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : $\;f_n:=n\,\left(x^{1/n}-1\right)\;$ will give $\,\log(x)$ as  $\,n\to\infty$ rather than $\,f_n:=x^{1/n}$.

Observe that for any positive $n$ we have :
$$\int x^{-1+1/n} \, dx=\frac{x^{1/n}}{1/n} + C=\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{1/n} +C'=\frac{e^{\,\large{\log(x)/n}}-1}{1/n} +C'$$ 
while the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the fraction obtained will be (for any fixed positive $x$) :
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{e^{\,\large{\log(x)/n}}-1}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{\log(x)/n}{1/n}=\log(x) $$
For alternative answers see this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498339/demystify-integration-of-int-frac1x-mathrm-dx).