# intuition of growth rate $\log N$ as $N^{1/\infty}$

Tags: calculus, algorithms

I wonder if it is widely taught, as far as heuristics go, that $\log N$ is just like $N^{1/\infty}$ (thinking something like $N^{0.00000000001}$). In other words, is there any danger in thinking this way?

I think a good test-case is deciding between $\log\log N$ and $\log^2 N := (\log N)^2$. (You may conclude that it doesn't help much.)

Comment: That is not widely taught (see the related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632349/whats-the-link-between-logarithms-and-the-zeroth-power-if-any ).  What is taught is that $\log N$ is growing (unbounded) but slower than $N^{1/k}$ for all $k$ however large.  Meanwhile $\log(\log N)$ grows even more slowly and the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) slower still

Comment: @Henry : But is $\log N$ in some reasonable sense the most rapidly growing thing that grows more slowly than $N^\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @Henry, thanks for confirming. Do people use $N^\epsilon$ instead? As heuristics go, I may perhaps venture to think (if not writing down in black-and-white) that $\log(\log N)$ is like $N^{1/2\infty}$ and $\log^* N$ is like $N^{1/N\infty}$. Disclaimer: I haven't had much experience working with such expressions, so I wanted to know what variety of expressions with $\log$ are out there.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It depends whether you regard things like $(\log N) \log(\log N)$ or $(\log N)^2$ as reasonable things.

Comment: It can be a useful heuristic to think of $\log(N)$ as some kind of "infinitesimal" power growth, like, perhaps, $1/\infty$ (whatever you want that to mean). But, as with all heuristics, it can help you figure out what your final result should be, but you need to figure out if you can get to it using rigorous methods.

Comment: @Henry : I suspect one could make a case that that way of looking at it is absolutely correct but silly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are probably correct, though it is a meaningful exercise to show that $\sum_3^\infty \frac1{N (\log N) \log(\log N)}$ is infinite and  $\sum_3^\infty \frac1{N (\log N)^2}$ is finite because the denominators grow at different speeds

Comment: @MichaelHardy An intermediate thing I see show up sometimes is growth like $\exp(\sqrt{\log n})$ (or some other power of $\log n$).  For example, the density of the largest known subset of $\{1,\dots,N\}$ without a $3$-term arithmetic progression decays like (the inverse of) this.  I don't recall this rate ever showing up in calculus classes though.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & \int_1^N u^{\varepsilon-1} \, du = O(N^\varepsilon) \text{ as } N\to\infty \text{ if } \varepsilon>0. \\ \\ & \int_1^N u^{\varepsilon-1} \, du = O(\log N) \text{ as }N\to\infty \text{ if } \varepsilon=0.  \end{align} $$

Comment: $$ \int_1^N u^{\varepsilon-1} \, du = \frac{N^\varepsilon - 1} \varepsilon \to \log N = \int_1^N u^{0-1} \, du \text{ as } \varepsilon\to0. $$