# How can the limit of $\int x^{a}$ be well-behaved if it is polynomial everywhere *except* at $\lim_\limits{a \rightarrow -1}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, logarithms

Normally when handling limits we consider a property of an expression to be valid at a limit of a parameter if that property is continuously true as we approach a limit of that parameter. For example: we can't divide by zero but we can divide by $a$ for arbitrarily small values of $a$ and show that this is valid $\lim_\limits{a\rightarrow 0}$.

Consider this:

We know that $\int x^{a}\mathrm{dx}$ is polynomial for $a\neq -1$

So surely $\lim_\limits{a\rightarrow -1} \int x^{a}$  is polynomial?

But we know this limit is actually $\ln(x)+C$ which is *not* a polynomial.

So the polynomial-ness of the result of integrating is violated $at$ the limit, even though it holds *as we approach* the limit.

So in what sense is this limit well-behaved?

Comment: Things staying true in the limit is practically the definition of "being closed". Apparently, the set of polynomials isn't closed.

Comment: $x^a$ and its integral are only polynomials when $a$ is a non-negative integer. If $a$ is restricted to integers, then you cannot take $\lim_{a\to -1}$, as the integers are discrete.

Comment: Also bear in mind that $\lim_{a\to-1}\int x^a$ technically doesn't make any sense as the integral is indefinite. If you wished to define a function, say: $$f(x)=\lim_{a\to-1}\int_1^x t^a\,\mathrm{d}t$$Then that makes sense

Comment: You might want to check out the Weierstrass theorem: that essentially says on any finite closed interval, you can make any continuous function be a limit of polynomial functions.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498339/demystify-integration-of-int-frac1x-mathrm-dx

Answer (score 1):

One approach:  Because of the $+C$ in an indefinite integral, I may say if we want to that
$$
\int x^a\;dx = \frac{x^{a+1}-1}{a+1}+C, \quad\text{for all } a \ne -1 ,
$$
and then we have the correct limit
$$
\lim_{a\to -1}\frac{x^{a+1}-1}{a+1} = \ln x .
$$