# Indeterminate form in solving an integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, infinity

I have this integral, and the solution gives an indeterminate form for the value $\alpha = 1$, can you explain to me how to solve the indeterminate form?

$$\int_{\beta}^{+\infty} x^{-\alpha} dx = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} \left[ x^{-\alpha + 1}\right]_{\beta}^{+\infty} = \frac{1}{0} \left[ +\infty^{0} - 1\right] =?$$

Little side note, I know the solution of this integral I am really just curious od knowing how to tackle the indeterminate form.

Comment: do you know what is $ \int \frac{dx}{x} $ ?

Comment: @what'sup - Yeah, log(x), so?

Comment: @what'sup - Maybe I should specify in the question that I know what shoul be the result, I am interested in understanding how to solve the indeterminate form...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64432/what-is-so-special-about-alpha-1-in-the-integral-of-x-alpha?lq=1
and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498339/demystify-integration-of-int-frac1x-dx?lq=1

Comment: @what'sup - very interesting links, thks a lot! But suppose I omit the previous part and just give you the indeterminate form, any clue on how to continue from there?

Comment: Such intgrals converge only for $\alpha>1$

Comment: @Matteo: the trick is to replace $\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \left[ x^{-\alpha + 1}\right]_{\beta}^{+\infty}\;$ by $\;\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \left[ x^{-\alpha + 1}-1\right]_{\beta}^{+\infty}\;$ to get a correct result at the limit (as shown in the two links proposed by what's up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really indeterminate.  What you are trying to do is
$$
\lim_{\alpha\to 1^+}\int_\beta^\infty x^{-\alpha}\,\, dx = \lim_{\alpha\to 1^+}\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}.
$$
But this is of the form $\displaystyle \frac{1}{0}$ which is not indeterminate.

Your issue is that to reach that last formula in your post you have to assume the integral exists.

Comment: but the integral does exist for $\alpha \to 1^{+}$

Comment: @Matteo: The integral exists for all $\alpha >1$.  So, we can try to see if the limit exists.  It makes no sense to say that the integral exists for $\alpha\rightarrow 1^+$.