# Integral of 1/x- why does it behave this way?

Tags: calculus, integration

First of all, I'm not entirely sure what to call polynomial functions that can have x raised to negative integers powers, so I will just call them *polynomial type* functions.

The integral of every *polynomial type* function is another *polynomial type* function, unless, of course, our *polynomial type* function has $\frac{1}{x}$ in it. In that case, our integral is obviously $\ln{x}$.

In the case of every other function in the form $x^{k}$ for some integer $k$, we can use power rule to find the integral. With $\frac{1}{x}$, there is a problem, since our integral will have had a constant of $0$ multiplying the term, nullifying it.

So my question is, why does it happen to be true that *every single polynomial type* function has a *polynomial type* integral, except $\frac{1}{x}$? $\frac{1}{x}$ happens to be the only function where using power rule to evaluate the integral doesn't work, and it also happens to the be the only one without a *polynomial type* integral.

This can't be a coincidence: the two special properties of $\frac{1}{x}$ must be related. What about $\frac{1}{x}$ makes it so special?

Comment: Functions involving negative (whole) powers of $x$ are called rational functions.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498381/328173) demonstrates the connection quite brilliantly in my opinion.

Comment: While the derivative of a rational function is always a rational function, anti-derivative of a rational function is not necessarily guaranteed to be a rational function. It is easy to prove using rules of derivatives that there is no rational function whose derivative is $1/x$ and with some more effort one can show that no algebraic function can have derivative $1/x$. So it's more a matter of the way derivatives and their rules work.

Comment: Good question, which fortunately already has a lot of good answers elsewhere. In addition to the one listed above, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118082/169852) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64432/169852)

Answer (score 2):

One way to see it is that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{x}$:
$$y=\ln(x)$$ $$e^y=x$$ Differentiating both sides with respect to x,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^y=1$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{e^y}$$
But remember that $e^y=x$. This means that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$
This means that the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ has to be $\ln(x)$.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that $\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't have a "polynomial type" derivative. From your definition $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a polynomial type function.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 1x$ does have a polynomial type derivative.  The derivative is $-\frac 1{x^2}$ which is polynomial type.  This is a central assumption of the question which is wrong.

Comment: There's a Latin phrase that summaries this answer nicely "a falsis principiis proficisci", meaning "you proceed from false principles"

Answer (score 0):

The integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is not a rational function. Several proofs of this can be found on this website. There are however power series expansions of $\ln(x)$ for some but not all of the real line. Recall the geometric series:
\begin{align*}
1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}
This series converges for $|x|<1$. Integrating both sides yields
\begin{align*}
\int(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)\,dx&=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{1-x}\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}
\end{align*}
This is a but unwieldy though because of the negative sign, so flipping this around gives
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}
\end{align*}
Using a change of variables and the definition of the natural logarithm, the power series on the RHS is equal to $\ln(1+x)$. So to summarize, the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ can represented as a power series, but not a rational function. If you want to see some more cool stuff like this, you can follow this [link](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/math214-2-04f/notes/c2-repfunpowser.pdf).

Comment: Are you sure every rational function can be expressed in the form as $F(x) $. Rational functions are ratios of polynomials.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Hmm, good point, I seem to have contradicted myself. I'll change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You also need to show why the relation $1/x=F'(x) =(p'(x) q(x) - p(x) q'(x)) /(q(x)) ^{2}$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, still working on it